# Diferença entre Arrays em Java

Tags: java, android, array

Qual o problema em Android de não definir o tamanho do array? Já vi em diversos lugares que este deve ser iniciado com um valor padrão.

Qual a diferença interna de se fazer isso:

```
 String[] array1 = new String[99]{};
```

Ou isso

```
 String[] array2 = {};
```

Além disso temos também o split, que pega uma sequência de caracteres e os quebra adicionando diretamente no array

```
String t = "Maçã, Banana, Pera";
```

Qual seria a diferença na hora que eu o adicionasse no array1 ou no 2?

```
array1 = t.split(",");
array2 = t.split(",");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`String[] array1 = new String[99];`

Fazendo isso você está inicializando um array de 99 posições no qual todas essas posições possuem o valor `null`. Os `{}` são inválidos nesse caso.
Nesse caso, `array1.length == 99`

`String[] array2 = {};`

Nesse caso você está inicializando um array com nenhum elemento. Logo, `array2.length == 0`
Fazer isso é a mesma coisa que fazer: `String[] array2 = new String[0]`.

Quando você executa a função de split, ela vai te retornar uma referência à um novo array, nesse caso um novo array de Strings.
Nesse seu exemplo, os valores de array1 e array2 vão ser os mesmos: `["Maçã", " Banana", " Pera"]`, mas vão ser dois arrays com referências diferentes, ou seja,
`array1 != array2`.

Logo, ao atribuir o valor de split nos arrays, você perdeu a referência que tinha deles antes, agora `array1` não é mais um array de 99 posições, e sim um de 3. Assim como `array2` não é mais um array vazio, e sim um array de 3 posições exatamente igual ao `array1` mas com outra referência.

Answer (score 2):

Todos eles possuem um valor fixo.

Quando eu uso o código abaixo, eu deixo explícito a quantidade de índices que o *array* deve ter, no caso 99 *strings*.

```
String[] array1 = new String[99];
```

É assim que o *Java* trabalha com *array*, toda e qualquer outra forma — até onde eu sei — são meros atalhos, explico mais adiante.

Quando inicializamos a variável durante a criação *(ver abaixo)*, nós fazermos um atalho para o código anterior.

```
String[] array2 = {"Pera", "Uva"};
```

Neste exemplo, o código é automaticamente convertido pelo compilador para `String[] array2 = new String[2];`. Você pode confirmar isso utilizando o código abaixo *(utilizei o Java `9.0.1`)*.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException;

public class HelloWorld
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    try {
        String[] array2 = {"Pera", "Uva"};
        array2[2] = "Maçã";

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array2));
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
      System.out.println("Não deu certo. O tamanho do índice foi extrapolado");
      System.out.println( e.toString() );
    }
  }
}
```

Saída esperada:

```
Não deu certo. O tamanho do índice foi extrapolado
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
```

Já o uso do `split`, ele altera esses valores do *array* e automaticamente atribui um valor fixo novamente.

Exemplo:

```
String[] array2 = {};
array2 = "Maçã, Banana, Pera".split(",");
```

O *Java* automaticamente “converte” e esse código para um *array* fixo e depois passa a referência dele para a variável *array2*.

Ps.: Caso queira testar os códigos, você pode utilizar https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler